# Comment out code by highlighting and simultaneously right clicking in Sublime Text

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

Rather than taking my hand of the mouse to use `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `/`, I'd like to be able to comment code by highlighting it, and then while keeping the left mouse button held down, simultaneously right click and have it comment out - though I don't know if that's possible with Sublime Text keybinds.

If not, I'll just use a custom keyboard shortcut, but I'd prefer the mouse method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can customize mousebinds by creating a file named `Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap`, `Default (OSX).sublime-mousemap`, `Default (Linux).sublime-mousemap` or (for any OS) `Default.sublime-mousemap` in your settings folder `\Packages\User` and then creating your custom bind inside that file
You can read more [here](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/key_bindings.html) (it's actually about keybinds but the process of creating mousebinds is the same.)

I came up with something similar to what you are trying to achieve but could not bind mouse1 as modifier so the snippet below is working different.
After you've made a selection, click and hold right mouse button and then click left mouse button to toggle comment block on selected area.

```
[
  {
     "button": "button1", "count": 1, "modifiers": ["button2"],
     "command": "toggle_comment", "args": {"block": true},
     "press_command": "drag_select_callback"
  }
]
```

This might be annoying if you comment something by accident, so you can change click to double click, by changing `count` value to 2 or 3 for triple click etc.

Block comment is defined by `{"block": true}`, if you would like line comments just change it to false

```
[
  {
     "button": "button1", "count": 1, "modifiers": ["button2"],
     "command": "toggle_comment", "args": {"block": false},
     "press_command": "drag_select_callback"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks adriano66 - I haven't gotten a chance to test it yet but I'll let you know as soon as I do.